# Can a mobile processor be Overclocked with Software means?

Tags: processes, arm-processors, processor

I was searching weather a mobile processor be Overclocked or not so i came across an answer saying no because processor operates on PLL(phase locked loop) which if set to a particular frequency can't be changed. But i have heard about Android Overclocking with some custom kernels and rooted devices. So i need some expert opinion on this matter.

Comment: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grarak.kerneladiutor

Comment: I don't know if there are hardware limitations of some processors. But kernel can definitely do overclocking. If kernel doesn't support OC, you can't do from userspace.